# Clone an HTML canvas and its content

Tags: javascript, html, html5-canvas, copy-paste

I have a piece of HTML code with a canvas I'd like to duplicate by the click of a button. I've tried this code so far but I'm a bit clueless about what's missing. If you could include any piece of code it would be really useful to me as I'm a beginner
Thank you

```
 <canvas id="myCanvas" width="800px" height="800px"></canvas>

    <script>
      var oldCnv = document.getElementById("myCanvas");

      function cloneCanvas(oldCanvas) {
        //create a new canvas
        var newCanvas = document.createElement("canvas");
        var context = newCanvas.getContext("2d");

        //set dimensions
        newCanvas.width = oldCanvas.width;
        newCanvas.height = oldCanvas.height;

        //apply the old canvas to the new one
        context.drawImage(oldCanvas, 0, 0);

        //return the new canvas
        return newCanvas;
        //append the new canvas on the page
        document.body.appendChild(newCanvas);
      }
    </script>
    <button onclick="cloneCanvas(oldCnv)">add canvas</button>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't pass the parameter oldCnv in an onclick action to the function. Besides that, after you `return newCanvas` the `document.body.appendChild(newCanvas)` won't get called.

The following will work.
Use this code:

```
 <canvas id="myCanvas" width="800px" height="800px"></canvas> 
   <script>
      var oldCanvas = document.getElementById("myCanvas");

      function cloneCanvas() {
        //create a new canvas
        var newCanvas = document.createElement("canvas");
        var context = newCanvas.getContext("2d");

        //set dimensions
        newCanvas.width = oldCanvas.width;
        newCanvas.height = oldCanvas.height;

        //apply the old canvas to the new one
        context.drawImage(oldCanvas, 0, 0);

        //return the new canvas
        //append the new canvas on the page
        document.body.appendChild(newCanvas);
      }
    </script>
    <button onclick="cloneCanvas()">add canvas</button>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Chiel!

Comment: @user13236143 Nice, if it was helpful please not forget to mark the question as answered!